# Do different diseases have different contagiousness / mortality rates?

Tags: banished

My village suffered a few disease outbreaks throughout the years, and so far it's always been very easy to survive them — typically, only one or two citizens get the disease and they're quickly treated.

The diseases were of different types: smallpox, dysentery etc... but they all seemed to work the same way, so I assumed it was just flavor text. This time however, I got the Plague, and it was radically more lethal: in about one minute of time at 10x, the disease has spread to 36 of my 380 citizens and killed 5 of them.

It might be related to the size of the settlement or something else, or it might be that different diseases have different effects. Does anyone know about this?

Edit: The disease is gone. It took my two doctors a season to cure and killed around 50 citizens.

Comment: Related: [How are diseases spread?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158119/how-are-diseases-spread)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some data about that on banished wikis like on this page : http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Disease

> The population may get sick naturally, or as the town grows as a
>   result of traders or nomads coming to the town. The population can
>   suffer from diseases such as influenza, plague and everything
>   in-between. Some diseases spread quickly, some linger, some have high
>   fatality rates, some low. The diseases will spread from citizen to
>   citizen based on health factors and proximity. Physicians and
>   Herbalists can help keep the population healthy and cure the diseases
>   in some cases.
>
> Taking in nomads significantly raises the risk of an outbreak of a
>   disease.
>
> Although foresters can plant new trees, the cures for many diseases
>   can only be found by Herbalists in forests that have existed for
>   decades.

Comment: Nice. Did someone compile a "ranking" of diseases?